# Class 'Ixudra\\Curl\\Facades\\Curl' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am working on a laravel project and using this curl package https://github.com/ixudra/curl

Everything works fine on my dev system but I am getting a `Class 'Ixudra\\Curl\\Facades\\Curl' not found` error on the staging after pushing to my git repo.

Here's my composer.json content

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
        "ejarnutowski/laravel-api-key": "^1.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.7",
        "ixudra/curl": "^6.19",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/nova": "*",
        "laravel/passport": "^8.4",
        "laravel/telescope": "^3.5",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-develop"
    },
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

or

```
composer update
```

I hope it helps !